# Looking to sort a list of servers by last letter before a number

Tags: bash, unix

I'd like to sort lines from a file that will allow me to sort alphabetically based "only" on the last letter before a number appears in a line. The numbers will only show up in the middle of a string. There is no limit to the amount of numbers or letters.

Example:

```
abcdef123ghi
abcd456efghijklm
ab24578cdef
```

I would expect the output of these 3 lines to come out as follows:

```
ab24578cdef #(alphabetically based on the "b")
abcd456efghijklm #(alphabetically based on the "d")
abcdef123ghi #(alphabetically based on the "f")
```

Thank you for any help!!!

Comment: Use `sed` or `awk` to split the line at that place, then sort it based on the second field, then remove the space with another `sed`.

Comment: After you split into multiple columns with sed or awk, the `sort -k` flag lets you sort based on a column other than the first.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that I'm a newbie when it comes to sed. What would I use to split the lines at those specific spots? I'm good with awk.

Comment: Can there be commas or spaces within the lines? Is there a minimum number of letters guaranteed to come before the first number? IE, how would you sort `2345asdfasfd`?

Comment: how would you sort when 2 (or more) items have the same `last letter before a number`, eg, `abc567` `abc783` `xyzc328` (all 3 have a `c` before the number so then how should they be sorted)?

Answer (score 3):

A [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform):

```sh
paste <(grep -oP '\D(?=\d)' file) file | sort -k1,1 | cut -f2-
```

Answer (score 1):

another one which scans the file just once.

```
$ sed -E 's/(.*([^0-9])[0-9].*)/\2\t\1/' file | sort | cut -f2-

ab24578cdef
abcd456efghijklm
abcdef123ghi
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused: digits come in the alphabet before letters, so a simple "sort" should do the trick. Imagine the mentioned are put in a file, let's say "file.txt", then the following command should solve your issue:

```
cat file.txt | sort
```

Comment: According to the requirements, `za1` should sort _before_ `ab1`

Answer (score 0):

A bit of fantasy:

```
$ cat test
abcdef123ghi
abcd456efghijklm
ab24578cdef
```

```
sed -E 's@^(.*)([^0-9])([0-9].*)$@\1 \2 \3@g' test |  sort -k 2 | sed 's@ @@g'
```

Result:

```
ab24578cdef
abcd456efghijklm
abcdef123ghi
```

Sed regex split the string in three chunks using a space:

```
1: from begin to not numeric value
2: single not numeric value followed by a number
3: all until end
```

Sort by second column

Sed remove all spaces